# Powemockito constructor testing problems

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, mockito

Hej I have some problems with TestNG and powerMockito 1.5.x I tried with 1.5.5 and 1.5.6. The problem is when I try to verify a constructor that is not empty.

I've check quite some examples around about extending from PowerMockTestCase and so on but they do not seem to work for me.

```
package com.cdev.common;
public class TestSubject {

    String data;
    String context;

    public TestSubject()
    {
        this.data = "Mock!!";
        this.context = "PowerMockito";

    }

    public TestSubject(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = "PowerMockito";
    }

    public TestSubject(String data,String context)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public String getContext()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

    }

    public boolean isNew()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

This is the testNG test:

```
package com.cdev.common.test;

import com.cdev.common.*;

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


@PrepareForTest({TestSubject.class})
public class TestSubjectTest{

    @Test
    public void TestSubject() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("======== Test ==================");

        TestSubject mockTestSubject = PowerMockito.mock(TestSubject.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(TestSubject.class).withArguments("A", "B").thenReturn(mockTestSubject);

        PowerMockito.when(mockTestSubject.getData()).thenReturn("A");
        PowerMockito.when(mockTestSubject.getContext()).thenReturn("B");
        PowerMockito.when(mockTestSubject.isNew()).thenReturn(true);


        PowerMockito.verifyNew(TestSubject.class).withArguments("A", "B");

        TestSubject lala = new TestSubject("A","B");

        System.out.println(lala.getData());
        System.out.println(lala.isNew());

        Assert.assertTrue(lala.getData().equals("A"), "Not equal");
    }
}
```

This gives me this output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse--2099806353/testng-customsuite.xml

======== Test ==================
FAILED: TestSubject
java.lang.AssertionError: Wanted but not invoked com.cdev.common.TestSubject(
    "A",
    "B"
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationControlAssertionError.throwAssertionErrorForNewSubstitutionFailure(InvocationControlAssertionError.java:93)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.verification.DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.invokeSubstitute(DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.java:51)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.verification.DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.withArguments(DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.java:44)
    at com.cdev.common.test.TestSubjectTest.TestSubject(TestSubjectTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6d9c638: 18 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@2401f4c3: 6 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@5d22bbb7: 3 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3d012ddd: 31 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 2 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1175e2db: 5 ms
```

Comment: So...why are you mocking something like this?  It doesn't seem that the newed object is deep within a dependency or anything.  You could test this explicitly with setters/getters or reflection.

Comment: Hej this is simply a prove of concept or a test to get a hold on powermockito so this is not really production code, if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `verifyNew` call to after the invocation has been made:

```
TestSubject lala = new TestSubject("A","B");
PowerMockito.verifyNew(TestSubject.class).withArguments("A", "B");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your instructions:

```
@Test
public void TestSubject() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("======== Test ==================");

    TestSubject mockTestSubject = PowerMockito.mock(TestSubject.class);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(TestSubject.class).withArguments("A", "B").thenReturn(mockTestSubject);

    PowerMockito.when(mockTestSubject.getData()).thenReturn("A");
    PowerMockito.when(mockTestSubject.getContext()).thenReturn("B");
    PowerMockito.when(mockTestSubject.isNew()).thenReturn(true);

    **TestSubject lala = new TestSubject("A","B");
    PowerMockito.verifyNew(TestSubject.class).withArguments("A", "B");**        

    System.out.println(lala.getData());
    System.out.println(lala.isNew());

    Assert.assertTrue(lala.getData().equals("A"), "Not equal");
}
```

The output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse--349458877/testng-customsuite.xml

======== Test ==================
FAILED: TestSubject
java.lang.AssertionError: Wanted but not invoked com.cdev.common.TestSubject(
    "A",
    "B"
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationControlAssertionError.throwAssertionErrorForNewSubstitutionFailure(InvocationControlAssertionError.java:93)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.verification.DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.invokeSubstitute(DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.java:51)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.verification.DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.withArguments(DefaultConstructorArgumentsVerfication.java:44)
    at com.cdev.common.test.TestSubjectTest.TestSubject(TestSubjectTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6d9c638: 36 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@2401f4c3: 8 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@5d22bbb7: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3d012ddd: 45 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@1175e2db: 5 ms
```